# Matrix Multiplication error in pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying out a linear model - however when I run it there is a mat mul error - between (32, 784) and (1,10)

the model:

```
class KMNIST_V1(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self,
               input: int,
               hidden_units: int,
               output: int):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer_stack = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(in_features = input,
                  out_features = hidden_units),
        nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_units,
                  out_features = hidden_units),
        nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_units,
                  out_features = output)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.layer_stack(x)`
```

I am unsure how to fix it I have tried multiplying the hidden_units by 784 but I have not been successful.

Comment: Please use a standard format for the code so that it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer - the error was when I assigned the model - I set the input as 1 not as 784 - so now the code runs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).